# Solving compound linear optimization problem

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, least-squares, quadprog

I would like to solve the following compound optimization problem in MATLAB:

```
min (Ax-a), min (Bx-b), min (Cx-c)
```

subject to `Dx=d` and `x>=0`, where `a,b,c,d` are vectors and `A,B,C,D` are matrices, all of them given.

First of all, I don't know how to set up the above problem, should I write

```
min(Ax-a)^2+(Bx-b)^2+(Cx-c)^2, s.t. Dx=d and x>=0
```

Is this the best formulation of such problem? The second question is, should I use quadprog or are there other more suitable routines in MATLAB?

Comment: We don't know what any of your variables are.  Are the capital letters matrices?  Could you better define your notation?

Comment: Hi, this looks interesting! To ensure we're able to provide quality answers, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You'll get much better feedback.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It is actually difficult to provide a minimal working example when one doesn't know how to formulate the problem in the first instance.

Comment: Do you have example `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` matrices with example `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` vectors?  That would be a good start.

Comment: Also, what version of MATLAB do you have?

Comment: This is a multi-objective problem. There is no single answer to this question. It depends a bit how to handle the trade-offs between the objectives. There is extensive literature on multi-objective optimization. You may want to do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed:

$$ \frac{1}{2} {\left| \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{a} \right|} + \frac{1}{2} {\left| \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b} \right|} = \frac{1}{2} {\left| \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{A} \ \boldsymbol{B} \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x} - \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{a} \ \boldsymbol{b} \end{bmatrix} \right|} = \frac{1}{2} {\left| \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{q} \right|} $$

[image]

If you apply this to all of your components you'd be left with Linear Least Squares with Linear Equality and Non Negativity Constraints. Which most [Quadratic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) solvers will be able to solve (See MATLAB's [`quadprog()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html)).